# Include from upper layer of files

Tags: meson-build

I've got main project structure in 1 folder, and units tests closed in another folder(2 different meson instances). In unit tests i need to include one file from main project(element to be tested). I dont want to specify relative path as i want to be portable between other programmers.

How can i instruct meson to first go back from current folder and then look through application files if there is file i'm looking for? I want to make it that way so any change in code can be tested right away without any copying or modifications.

```
C:\Users\User1\Project\application
C:\Users\User1\Project\unittests
```

I need to be able to see files from application while beeing currently on unittests

Answer (score 0):

Declare project dependency at top level `meson.build` like

`project_dep = declare_dependency(include_directories: inc_dir, sources: srcs, dependencies:[...])`

Make sure that your `main` is not in the `sources`. In test level `meson.build`
include `project_dep` like this:

```
unit_tests_exec = executable('UnitTests', gtest_srcs, 
dependencies :[gtest_dep, gmock_dep, project_dep])
```

You can check how I organized project using `meson` for `Tdd` session here: 
https://github.com/elvisoric/tdd_session